# How do I loop this code until the user enters -1?

Tags: java

I'm kinda new to java and I was wondering how  to loop this code until someone enters -1 and how to add "out of bounds" if the user enters number not between 0-100?

here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Question2 {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         int count = 0;
         int a = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 99);
         int guess = 0;

      System.out.println("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game");
      System.out.print("Guess a number between 0 and 100 or enter -1 to end: ");

      while (guess != a) {
        guess = keyboard.nextInt();
         count++;
        if (guess > a) {
            System.out.print("The number is lower. Try again: ");
        } 
        else if (guess < a) {
            System.out.print("The number is higher. Try again: ");
        }
        else if (guess == a) {
        System.out.println("Congratulations. You guessed the number in "
        + count + " tries!");
       }
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: `while (guess != a && guess != -1) {`, although I'd be tempted to use a `do-while` loop instead

Comment: Did my answer work? Feel free to ask me any questions if it didn't. If it did, make sure to mark it best answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the bounds within the for loop. In order to stop further checks, you can iterate to the next loop through the continue call. Otherwise, if you actually want to break out of the loop, use the break call (for the -1 case).

```
while (guess != a) {
    guess = keyboard.nextInt();
     count++;
    if (guess < 0 || guess > 100){
        if(guess == -1)
             break;
        System.out.println("Out of bounds");
        continue;
    }
    if (guess > a) {
        System.out.print("The number is lower. Try again: ");
    } 
    else if (guess < a) {
        System.out.print("The number is higher. Try again: ");
    }
    else if (guess == a) {
    System.out.println("Congratulations. You guessed the number in "
    + count + " tries!");
 }
 System.out.println("Thank-you for playing the game!!");
```

Comment: how will i put "Thank you for playing the game!" if the user entered "-1"?

Comment: I would just put that print statement outside of the while loop. I edited the answer

Comment: If I enter "-1" it still prints the "out of bounds" statement. How do I remove that?

Comment: Well, I made it like that cause it is technically out of bounds. Just move the if statement with the -1 to the beginning of the body. Look at the code

Comment: Are you talking about the "Thank-you for playing the game!!"? That's just a quick fix in the print statement.

Comment: no, i'm talking about the "guess the number" again. How do i continuously loop it even after I entered the correct guess on the first?

Comment: just put the whole thing in a while(true) block but you have to return instead of break for the -1

Answer (score 0):

You want to **do** some code **while** something is not = to -1. In java, we use

```
!=
```

to represent not equal. So, try this code with the do while in mind:

```
do{

        guess = keyboard.nextInt();
         count++;
        if (guess > a) {
            System.out.print("The number is lower. Try again: ");
        } 
        else if (guess < a) {
            System.out.print("The number is higher. Try again: ");
        }
        else if (guess == a) {
        System.out.println("Congratulations. You guessed the number in "
        + count + " tries!");
       }

   }
}
\\Here comes the **while**

} while (guess != a && keyboard.in != -1)
```

The while states that when guess is not a **AND** the user has not entered -1. This is the **only** way that the do can be executed.

Thats it! I suggest you read more about math operations and loops.

Best of luck,

```
{Rich}
```